# channel.asFlux() seems to cause deadlock in high concurrency scenario

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Ok I've edited the whole question and produced two version of code which seems more interesting to show up the issue.. 
there are 2 functions here, one cause deadlock the other not..
the problem  seems to be inside `channel.asFlux()`  conversion but I don't understand what is the best practice to avoid such locks..

thank you,
Francesco

```
    @Test
    @Disabled("investigating..")
    fun tt() = runBlocking<Unit>{
        (0..3000).map { async {
            //noDeadLock()
            yesDeadLock()
        }}.forEach { it.await()}
    }


    val thPool = newSingleThreadContext("single")
    suspend fun yesDeadLock(){
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ DEADLOCK
            var channel = Channel<Int>(Channel.RENDEZVOUS)
            val producer =
                launch(newSingleThreadContext("nconte")){
                    while (isActive  && !channel.isClosedForSend && !channel.isClosedForReceive ){
                        try{
                            channel.send(1)
                        }catch (t:Throwable){
                        }
                    }
                }

            withContext(Dispatchers.Default){ 
            // withContext(thPool){  // <<-- with any other context, even a single thread, this long cause deadlocks
                channel.asFlux()
                    .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic(),1)
                    .doFinally {  producer.cancel() }
                    .limitRate(1)
                    .take(30)
                    .blockLast()
            }
            1
        }
    }

    suspend fun noDeadLock(){
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default){ 
            var channel = Channel<Int>(Channel.RENDEZVOUS)
            val producer =
                launch(newSingleThreadContext("nconte")){
                    while (isActive  && !channel.isClosedForSend && !channel.isClosedForReceive ){
                        try{
                            channel.send(1)
                        }catch (t:Throwable){
                        }
                    }
                }

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ 
                channel.asFlux()
                    .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic(),1)
                    .doFinally {  producer.cancel() }
                    .limitRate(1)
                    .take(30)
                    .blockLast()
            }
            1
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to add that this line is the issue `withContext(Dispatchers.Default){`

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding new elements as comments.

Comment: wow -1 for that ? or because the content of the question ? I've provided full working code for my question ..

Comment: I don't know, I wasn't the one giving -1. But yeah, making your question as easy as possible to read might increase your changes of getting an answer.

Comment: this code seems big but it's just 5 lines of business code.. the rest are function/variable declaration , error handling and log, I don't see that code so hard to read.. what I find hard is that this deadlock has surfaced suddenly in my code and I still don't have found a solution for it. I think It's an interesting question provided with a very specific test in just a handful lines of code n I'll be more specific on the title once I've found the exact issue..

Comment: You've just blocked all the treads in the default thread pool with `blockLast`. Don't block and you'll have no problems.

Comment: Thank for your reply Roman, I follow your works :) , what seems counter-intuitive here is that blockLast is awaiting (I know in disp.Default which is bad , but for an immediate function should be even acceptable.. )  but producer are not in same dispatchers, each producer is launched early in another thread! so the waits should come to an end ( I've created a slightly less verbose gist : https://gist.github.com/fvigotti/9edaa94546f5ecb3e354bfc180b91b91 )  , I mean I understand It's blocked and where but I don't feel confident on why and how to avoid in future/complex program..

Comment: I've updated the gist with a more minimal example : https://gist.github.com/fvigotti/9edaa94546f5ecb3e354bfc180b91b91 , now there is a take(1), the producer job will autoCancel,  and I want to tell also that if you use `withContext(thPool){ ` for the fluxConsumer it works.. which is one thread only! , there must be some operations which concurr in `Dispatchers.Default` which make the whole operating on flux on this dispatcher very dangerous ( and cause the deadlock )  I think that If it isn't an error there should be a warning in the documentation maybe..?

Comment: even using     val thPool2 = newFixedThreadPoolContext(8,"single")
 for the flux() consumer doesn't deadlock... so probably there some operations in the conversion between the channel to flux that must have access to a free Dispatcher.Main thread, what has been confusing for me is that the producer operation was already launched so the blocking should not have problems even if it's blocked because the lock will be released by the producer downstream-data-coming , but probably some other coroutines want access to that thread for the conversion and that's has been the confusing part for me..

Comment: To put that in other words, for what I understood It is "ok/not-deadlocking" to block channel->flux conversion on every thread/threadpool you want , but not in Dispatcher.Default pool this is not documented and I don't understand why, while everything else in the program (expecially the producer) is out of Dispatcher.Default , failing to understand exactly why this happens force me to avoid Dispatchers.Default at any cost because I Don't know if a library blocking operations may cause some deadlock.. even if the data the `library` is waiting for is becoming available from a non locked thread..